# Adding Version from Release tags to build using github actions

Tags: python, package, github-actions, pypi

Guys I am trying to release my package but every time its failing at the build stage as it is trying to reference 0.1.0 which I had released for testing and deleted them.

In the `setup.py`, I have updated the version to 0.1.1 but still whenever I am creating a new release it is building as 0.1.0.

How do I add the release tag that I am using to the .yml file.

This is the structure of the .yml file

```yaml
name: Upload Python Package

on:
  release:
    types: [published]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  deploy:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.x'
    - name: Check that tag version matches code version
      run: |
          tag=${GITHUB_REF#refs/tags/}
          version=$(python setup.py --version)
          echo 'tag='$tag
          echo "version file="$version
          test "$tag" == "$version"
    
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install build
    - name: Build package
      run: python -m build
```

Contents of setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

# from sphinx.setup_command import BuildDoc

with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="arxiv-summarizer",
    version="0.1.1",
    description="A happy toolkit for arxiv paper summarization and understanding.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/ArchanGhosh/Arxiv-Summarizer",
    project_urls={
        "GitHub": "https://github.com/ArchanGhosh/Arxiv-Summarizer",
        "Homepage": "https://github.com/ArchanGhosh/Arxiv-Summarizer",
    },
    author="",
    author_email="",
    maintainer="",
    maintainer_email="",
    keywords="",
    license="Apache",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages(where="src"),
    include_package_data=True,
    py_modules=['__main__'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'arxiv_summarizer = arxiv_summarizer.__main__:cli',
        ],
    },
    # cmdclass={"build_sphinx": BuildDoc},
    # these are optional and override conf.py settings
    command_options={
        "build_sphinx": {
            "project": ("setup.py", ""),
            "version": ("setup.py", "0.1.1a"),
            "release": ("setup.py", "0.1"),
            "source_dir": ("setup.py", "docs"),
        }
    },
    install_requires=[
        # Arxiv & PDF
        "langchain",    # For loading Arxiv PDFs
        "arxiv",        # `langchain` dependency
        "pymupdf",      # `langchain` dependency

        # ML
        "transformers", # For Transformer models
        #"gradio",       # For Web Interface
        "torch==2.1.2", # For Machine Learning

        # CLI
        "click",        # For CLI arguments
        "rich",         # For Rich Text in CLI

        # Tests
        "pytest",       # For Unit Tests
    ],
    extras_require={
        "dev": [
            "nox",
            "pytest",
        ],
        "docs": [
            "sphinx",
            "sphinxemoji",
            "pydata-sphinx-theme",
            "numpydoc",
            "sphinx_panels",
            "matplotlib",
            "Ipython",
            "sphinx-hoverxref",
        ],
    },
    classifiers=[
        # License
        "License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License",
        # Project Maturity
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        # Topic
        "Topic :: Communications",
        # Intended Audience
        "Intended Audience :: Science/Research",
        # Compatibility
        "Operating System :: Microsoft :: Windows",
        "Operating System :: MacOS",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
        #Environment
        "Environment :: Console",
        "Environment :: GPU",
        
        # Python Version
        #"Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        #"Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4",
        #"Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
        #"Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6",
        #"Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11",
    ],
)
```

[build error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S38S.jpg)
Getting a new release id in place of the older one.

Comment: Are you updating the version in the `setup.py` using the tag?

Comment: yes I have updated the version tag in setup.py
```
setup(
    name="",
    version="0.1.1",
..
..
..

```

Comment: Right. Please add the contents of `setup.py` in your question along with the logs of your build steps as text.

Comment: Added the picture as I have deleted the workflow from github actions

Comment: That's the output of your publish step. Please include the output of the build step also. In the publish logs, the built artifacts is showing the version 0.1.0, not the updated one.

Comment: @Azeem I was able to fix it by deleting the entire tag and recreating it after a final push. It was referencing till the last commit before tag creation and not post that, so the setup.py was changed along with some other files after we created tag v0.1.1 hence it didn't work. After clearing the entire tag and tag cache it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The Tag under release must be created after the final commit that is to be appended in that release.

Our mistake was the release tag was created an hour before the final release commit was made, which was not taking the last few commits into consideration.